# gitignore question- how do I add a Windows shortcut file to gitignore

Tags: github

I have some Windows shortcut files in my project folder that I don't need on my git when I do a push.
How do I tell git to ignore them?

In my Windows Explorer, I have, for example, this shortcut:
"LED Curtain.sch - Shortcut"

I've tried putting that line into .gitignore, and I've tried putting *.sch into .gitignore, but the shortcut keeps getting into my git.

What am I missing?

Comment: It's not only `.lnk` but also `.url`

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following in .gitignore file worked for me to avoid pushing shortcut folder into github.

```
## git ignore shortcut folder
*.lnk
```